# Check given username and password in a WPF app

Tags: sql, wpf, authentication

How can you check the given username and password as a string with records out of a sql server database?

The password's are hashpasswords, so the given password as string can't be matched with one from the db.

Do I need to use a sql function that returns true if a user is found?

Comment: The normal way to do this is to hash the given password using the same hashing function as is used on the passwords in the database, then compare the two hashed passwords. By the way, what does this have to do with WPF?

Comment: Because I can't find how to compare string passwords with hashed passwords

Comment: @user2970725, at least you need to know the hash method which your user table is using; then hash the password in your wpf app then comapre.